# Making subsite page the homepage in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to make a subsite page as the homepage in sharepoint without any access to codes to location where all the files are stored?

Comment: Uhmm what? All files in SharePoint is stored in the database, especially the subsite pages. But generally I'd say that what you are trying to achieve isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently subsites cannot be made welcome page directly due to some security issues. It is possible to create a redirect page in the main site and make it the landing page and then redirect the user to the subsite from there.